# C character-by-character string manipulation from const char *src to char *dest

Tags: c, strcat

I am trying to copy char one by one from one pointer to another with some manipulations. I tried using strcat(), strncat(), strcpy(), strncpy() but keep getting errors. How can I copy a char from source pointer to destination pointer? 
I originally passed single quotes as arg 2 of strcat and it did not work. When I changed it to double quotes, it worked. Does it have something to do with "string constants" vs 'character constants' or something entirely different?

```
void korsoroi(char *dest, const char *src) {
    int wcount = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (src[i] != '\0') {

        if (src[i] == 'k' && src[i + 1] == 's') {
            strcat(dest, "x");
            i++;
        } 
        else if (src[i] == 't' && src[i + 1] == 's') {
            strcat(dest, "z");
            i++;
        } 
        else if (src[i] == ' ') {
            wcount++;
            if (wcount % 3 == 0) {
                strcat(dest, " niinku");
            }
            if (wcount % 4 == 0) {
                strcat(dest, " totanoin");
            }
        } 
        else {
        //expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'
//            strcat(dest, src[i]);
//            strcat(dest, *(src + i);

        //warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
//            strcat(dest, (char*)src[i]);

        //returns strange characters but compiles
        //dest[strlen(dest)] = src[i];


        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

http://2016-aalto-c.tmchq.co/en/Module_2/
Task 08

Comment: is `dest` writable and has enough memory?

Comment: You can assume that the there is enough space at address dest to store the resulting string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a pointer keeping track of the end of `dest`. As you add more things at the end of `dest`, you increase this other pointer accordingly. Example:

```
void korsoroi(char *dest, const char *src)
{
  char*  dest_ptr = &dest[strlen(dest)]; // point at end of string

  for(; *src != '\0; src++)
  {
    if(src[i] == whatever)
    {
      strcpy(dest_ptr, "something");
      dest_ptr += sizeof("something");
    }
    else
    {
      *dest_ptr = *src;
      dest_ptr++;
    }
  }

  *dest_ptr = '\0';
}
```

Also, if you are going to use `src[i+1]` then you first need to check that `src[i+1]` is not `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

In `strcat(dest, src[i]);`, the second argument is a `char` not a `char *`.

You need to use `src+i` instead to have a `char *` . This will copy the whole remaining string, not sure if you want that, but otherwise you need to create a dummy `char *` with only one char in it, or use another approach.

Comment: How would you approach this problem?

Comment: A better way (instead of using `strcat`) to build `dest` is by having an index (for example `z`) and concatenate chars with `dest[z++] = src[i]`. The function `strcat` is inefficient and not designed for just appending single chars.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here is to directly copy from `src` to `dest`

If you want to copy the `xth` byte in source, to the `yth` location in dest, then you can use.

```
dest[y] = src[x]
```

Then you can wrap it around a loop, to copy as many bytes as you want.

Don't forget to add a `\0` at the end of `dest`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```
void korsoroi(char *dest, const char *src) {
        int count = 0;
        while (*src) {
            if (*src == 'k' && *(src + 1) == 's') {
                *dest++ = 'x';
                src++;
            } else if (*src == 't' && *(src + 1) == 's') {
                *dest++ = 'z';
                src++;
            } else if (*src == ' ') {
                *dest++ = ' ';
                count++;
                if (!(count % 3)) {
                    strcpy(dest, "niinku");
                    dest += strlen("niinku");
                    if(*(src + 1)){
                        *dest++ = ' ';
                    }
                } else if (!(count % 4)) {
                    strcpy(dest, "totanoin");
                    dest += strlen("totanoin");
                    if(*(src + 1)){
                        *dest++ = ' ';
                    }                
                }
            } else {
                *dest++ = *src;
            }
            src++;
        }
        *dest = '\0';
    }
```